# Run pyinstaller within virtual environment from batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, pyinstaller

What I am trying to do is create a batch file to create a virtual environment, install requirements, and then use pyinstaller to convert the python file to an executable.

I have a folder (.venv) with the following folders/files:

- upx (folder with the upx .exe)

In the parent folder there is:

- fileName.py
- icon.ico
- compileEXE.bat

The Code:

```
copy fileName.py .venv
copy icon.ico .venv

cd .venv

@echo off
Set "out=."
(
    Echo;pytube==15.0.0
    Echo;moviepy==1.0.3
    Echo;keyboard==0.13.5
) > "%out%\requirements.txt"

echo;requirements.txt created

@echo on
python -m venv fileName

cmd /k "pip install -r requirements.txt"

fileName\Scripts\activate.bat

pyinstaller fileName.py -F --icon=icon.ico --upx-dir upx
```

### I have tried changing the last line, with no luck, to:

`start /b "" "python.exe" "pyinstaller fileName.py -F --icon=icon.ico --upx-dir upx`

`cmd /k "pyinstaller fileName.py -F --icon=icon.ico --upx-dir upx`

## Expected Outcome:

- fileName.exe is created in the venv/dist folder
- virtual environment *fileName* with dependencies is created
- icon.ico, fileName.py is moved
- requirements.txt is created

## Actual Outcome:

- virtual environment *fileName* with dependencies is created
- icon.ico, fileName.py is moved
- requirements.txt is created

I can run the last line in the terminal and pyinstaller will work. 


How do I execute this last line within the virtual environment from the Batch file?

Comment: Modify `cmd /k "pip install -r requirements.txt"` to `pip install -r requirements.txt`. There is already `cmd.exe` running for processing the batch file. Modify `fileName\Scripts\activate.bat` to `call fileName\Scripts\activate.bat` as otherwise the *Windows Command Processor* __continues__ batch file processing with processing `activate.bat` with never coming back to the batch file written by you. The command __CALL__ is for calling a batch file from within a batch file. There can be added at bottom the command `pause` if `cmd.exe` should halt batch file processing until a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17829451/alexander) and [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) for the help.

Including pyinstaller in the requirements.txt file reduced the file size by 50% and the call function worked perfectly. This is my final code:

```
copy fileName.py .venv
copy icon.ico .venv

cd .venv

@echo off
Set out="."
(
    Echo;pytube==15.0.0
    Echo;moviepy==1.0.3
    Echo;keyboard==0.13.5
    Echo;pyinstaller==5.10.1
) > "%out%\requirements.txt"

echo;requirements.txt created

@echo on
python -m venv fileName

pip install -r requirements.txt

call fileName\Scripts\activate.bat

pyinstaller fileName.py -F --icon=icon.ico --upx-dir upx
```

Answer (score 0):

When you activate a virtual environment it launches a brand new shell, but all of the remaining commands from your script are not transferred to this new shell, they are still executed in the original.

One way to get around this is to never activate the the environment in the first place and instead just reference the newly created python and pip executables directly in your commands.

For example:

```
copy fileName.py .venv
copy icon.ico .venv

cd .venv

@echo off
Set out="."
Set scripts=fileName\scripts
Set pyinstaller=fileName\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller

Set
(
    Echo;pytube==15.0.0
    Echo;moviepy==1.0.3
    Echo;keyboard==0.13.5
    Echo;pyinstaller
) > "%out%\requirements.txt"

echo;requirements.txt created

@echo on
python -m venv fileName

%scripts%\pip.exe install -r requirements.txt

%scripts%\python.exe %pyinstaller% fileName.py -F --icon=icon.ico
```

I added pyinstaller to the list of requirements because you should always install pyinstaller in the environment that you want pyinstaller to use when compiling the executable.